# How can I quickly change the cell that many of my formulas point to?

Tags: excel

I've got a spreadsheet that has a bunch of cells with simple formulas that look like: =(column letter)(row)/(column letter)(row). =E92/E77 for example. There are 6 rows of 12 of these formulas, and I want to change the divisor row (77 in example) to a different row for each of them. Now I know that I can just change the first one in each of the 6 rows and drag the formula across the remaining columns for each row.

I want to know is there a quicker way to change a cell reference (terminology?) for many cells?

I hope the question is clear enough, if it is not then say so and I will try to clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is not related to programming. It is a better fit for http://superuser.com. Don't worry about it, we'll move it there. But keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: Doh! Sorry. I checked to see if there were other questions about excel here and saw that there are 5800+ with excel tags, and figured that it would be okay, but I guess they are all more related to programming. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea is to name your cells (or even ranges), using the textbox left of the formula bar. You know, the one with with current cell coordinates. Just select the cell, type in the name, and press Enter.

Then, you use that name instead of the cell coordinates in your formulas. If you ever need to change it, you can use the Name Manager and change the name to point